# How to use styling file (abstract.sty) in latex?

Tags: formatting, packages, pdf, compiling

I'm new to LaTeX. What I need to do is to write an A4 pdf abstract of my research using LaTeX. The format is given. What I only have is `abstract.sty` file. Following the tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CmagZthwhaY, I have just installed `LaTex Workshop` extension in my VScode. I also installed MicTeX. I am learning LaTeX but I find it overwhelming.

I put 2 files in my working directory:

- abstract.sty
- main.tex

main.tex is very simple:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{abstract}

\title{Scene classification based on motion-skill}
\author{Turuu}
\date{October 10th, 2023}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

abstract.sty is here:

```
% ------------------------------------------------------------------
%　　学部卒業研究発表概要スタイル
%　　December, 2013
%　　by Shohei Masuda
%　　Last Update : Dec. 5, 2013
% ------------------------------------------------------------------
\typeout{Bachelor's abstract}
\typeout{December 5, 2013}
\typeout{by Shohei Masuda}

% A4 size : (210mm x 297mm)
\setlength{\topmargin}{-15.4truemm} %上余白
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-5.4truemm}  %左余白
\setlength{\headheight}{0truemm}        %ヘッダ領域
\setlength{\headsep}{0truemm}           %ヘッダ-本文
\setlength{\textwidth}{170truemm}       %本文幅
\setlength{\textheight}{277truemm}      %本文高さ

%アブストラクトの左右にスペースを開ける
\def\flushleft#1#2{%
    \trivlist\raggedright
    \rightskip#2
    \leftskip#1
    \item\relax}

%アブストラクト用インデント
\def\IndentEng{%
    \hspace{1em}}

%タイトル
\def\Title#1{\gdef\@Title{#1}}
\gdef\@Title{}
%名前
\def\Name#1{\gdef\@Name{#1}}
\gdef\@Name{}
%学籍番号
\def\StudentNumber#1{\gdef\@StudentNumber{#1}}
\gdef\@StudentNumber{}
%指導教員
\def\Teacher#1{\gdef\@Teacher{#1}}
\gdef\@Teacher{}
%英語アブストラクト
\def\AbstractText#1{\gdef\@AbstractText{#1}}
\gdef\@AbstractText{}

%section類の再定義
\renewcommand{\section}{%
    \if@slide\clearpage\fi
    \@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}%
    {1.2zh}% 前アキ
    {0.2zh}% 後アキ
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\headfont\raggedright}%
}%
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
    {0zh}{0.2zh}%
    {\normalfont\normalsize\headfont}%
}%
\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
    {0zh}{0.2zh}%
    {\normalfont\normalsize\headfont}%
}%

%タイトル部分
\def\TitleText{%
\twocolumn[
    \begin{center}
        %タイトル
        {\Large\bfseries \@Title }
        \vspace{1zw}
    \end{center}
    \begin{center}
        %学籍番号等
        {\large\bfseries 学籍番号:\ \@StudentNumber \hspace{2mm} \@Name\ \hspace{5mm} 指導教員:\ \@Teacher}
        \vspace{1zw}
    \end{center}
    \begin{flushleft}{2zw}{2zw}
        %アブストラクト
        Abstract:\,\@AbstractText
    \end{flushleft}
    \vspace{1zh}
]}

%行間の設定
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.9}
%図などのマージンなし
\setlength\floatsep{0pt}
\setlength\textfloatsep{0pt}
\setlength\intextsep{0pt}
\setlength\abovecaptionskip{0pt}
%ページ番号なし
\pagestyle{empty}
%subsubsectionまで
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
```

However, I'm getting errors. I have no clue what is wrong. Can you please explain to me what am I missing?
[image]

I know something is very wrong. The pdf file looks like this:
[image]

Comment: just remove abstract.sty it appears to be designed as an extension to the slides class and can't be used with normal  latex classes.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Do you think I can just abandon the abstract.sty and write the paper in my style? The professor probably wanted everyone to follow the same format.

Comment: abstract.sty does not do anything possibly useful for a normal document. what did you expect it to do?

Comment: If your professor told you to use that he's either wrong or he meant a different file than the one you found. Either way better to ask your professor than ask me. I can not possibly guess what he or she wants/

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh, okay. A senior student gave me this file. I think he gave me the wrong file or something.